# print total of 'du' for one filetype, directory is not flat

Tags: linux, bash, du

I have a directory with multiple filetypes, directories absolutely not flat with variable depths.
**I'd like to know the volume size a given filetype is occupying.**

I was thinking of filtering after du and then summing

```
du -ah . | grep .extension | sum
```

It does print something but sum surely doesn't do what I expected. I tested

```
du -ah . | grep -v .extension | sum
```

and values don't add up to the directory size :

```
du -ahc .
```

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -type f -name '*.extension' -exec du -ch {} +
```

Thanks : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41550/find-the-total-size-of-certain-files-within-a-directory-branch

Answer (score -1):

You could use [bs - byte summer](https://github.com/MarianoGappa/bs):

```
ls -lhR | awk '{ if (NF==9) print }' | grep '.*.extension' | bs
```

Gives you a few advantages over the `find`-based solution:

- With the `-u` option, you can force the unit of output (e.g. GB, MB)
- Composability: `-u` gives you numeric output, which you can compose with say [bc](http://ss64.com/bash/bc.html)
- grep allows more flexible (though fallible) filtering: could filter based on permissions, date, etc.
- Less verbose: just gives you the total